Is there a TMSL script equivalent to Applying a Policy Refresh in Tabular Editor?
Tabular Editor is an option if you want to manually apply policy refresh for a certain table or your model. However I want this to be in a form of script to make it easier for me. Is there an equivalent TMSL script for this?

Refreshing a policy isn't directly supported but you can use a TMSL script to refresh table partitions, which in turn would refresh the data within the context of the security roles so in an indirect way  refreshing the policy as well :
{
  "refresh": {
    "type": "full",
    "objects": [
      {
        "database": "YourDatabaseName",
        "table": "YourTableName"
      }
    ]
  }
}

